# How to count # of patterns in a sequence

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Definition: A sequence has a pattern if the sequence contains all of the elements of the pattern, in order, but not necessarily consecutively. For example, 'abc' has pattern a, b, c, ab, ac, bc and abc, but not ca. Or by codes

```
def has_pattern(pat, lst):
  pat_i = 0
  for el in lst:
    if el == pat[pat_i]:
      pat_i += 1
      if pat_i == len(pat):
        return True
      continue
  return False
```

What I want is given a pattern and a sequence, the probability of a permutation of the sequence has the pattern. This function does the job

```
def prob(pat, lst):
  all_perm = list(itertools.permutations(lst, len(lst)))
  return Fraction(sum((has_pattern(pat, p) for p in all_perm)), len(all_perm))
```

but it's slow and I want a general formula so I can get, for example, prob(‘abc’, ‘aabbcc’) = 47/90, quickly.
What I can see is
1. Letters in the sequence but not in the pattern doesn't matter. prob('ab', 'abc') = prob('ab', 'ab')
2. The order of pattern doesn't matter. prob('ab', 'ab') = prob('ba', 'ab')
3, then?
Thanks.

Comment: Defining something by code is not necessarily a great idea.  In this case, you mean has_pattern(pat, lst) if for some subsequence $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_n$, not necessarily consecutive, we have pat[$i$] = lst[$a_i$] for every character in pat, right?  E.g. has_pattern('abc', 'xaybdddc') is True.

Comment: number of subsets if all are distinct ...  sub-multisets if not.

Comment: @antkam You're right. Sorry I'm not that good in expressing this in English.

Comment: No problem.  Many people at MSE are not native English speakers.  Examples (like your new, extended example) are still better than code IMHO.  Anyway, very interesting problem!

Comment: If the letters of pat appear in lst exactly the same number of times, the problem is easy.  but if some letters of pat appear more often in lst than in pat, this looks like a non-trivial problem (maybe inclusion-exclusion?)  @RoddyMacPhee - I don't understand your comment.  What do you mean by "sub-multisets"?  Can you elaborate how that helps?

Comment: because the number of distinct selections is the number of non-empty subsets of the set. there are $2^n-1$ for $n$ distinct items. in the case of repeats, it's simply the number of subsets with distinct multiplicities, as sets don't generally care about repeats it's subsets of a multiset, or a sub-multiset.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee - if I understand correctly, you permute lst randomly.  so e.g. if lst='aabbcc', the permuted version 'bcaacb' would not contain pat='abc' but the permuted version 'baacbc' would contain pat='abc'. I dont undertand what 'number of subsets' have to do with this.  Can you write out a full answer?

Answer (score 0):

Answering for myself. I got some progress and just need the last leap. I notice that having a pattern, for example 'abc', can be equivalently expressed in regex as 
"^[abc]*a[bc]*b[ac]*c[ab]*$". Every letter can be followed by a group of letters other than it, plus a group of all letters at the beginning. The problem turns to how to assign letters to allowed groups. This function will calculate the count of pattern 'abc'.

```
def abc_ct(seq):
  a, b, c = 'a', 'b', 'c'
  if not isinstance(seq, Counter):
    seq = Counter(seq)
  seq = Counter({k: v for k, v in seq.items() if k in ('a', 'b', 'c'})
  n_perm = math.factorial(sum(seq.values()))
  ct = 0  # ^[abc]*a[bc]*b[ac]*c[ab]*$
  for a1 in range(seq[a]):  # a in ^[abc]
    for b1 in range(seq[b]):  # b in ^[abc]
      for c1 in range(seq[c]):  # c in ^[abc]
        for b2 in range(seq[b] - b1):  # b in [bc]
          for c2 in range(seq[c] - c1):  # c in [bc]
            for a2 in range(seq[a] - a1):  # a in [ac]
              abc_ct = math.factorial(a1 + b1 + c1) // math.factorial(a1) // math.factorial(b1) // math.factorial(c1)
              bc_ct = binomial(b2 + c2, b2)
              ac_ct = binomial(a2 + seq[c] - c1 - c2 - 1, a2)
              ab_ct = binomial(seq[a] - a1 - a2 + seq[b] - b1 - b2 - 2, seq[a] - a1 - a2 - 1)
              p = abc_ct * bc_ct * ac_ct * ab_ct
              ct += p
  ct *= math.factorial(seq[a]) * math.factorial(seq[b]) * math.factorial(seq[c])
  return Fraction(ct, n_perm)
```

More generally, this function works for any case.

```
def prob_general(pat, seq):
  if not isinstance(pat, Counter):
    pat = Counter(pat)
  if not isinstance(seq, Counter):
    seq = Counter(seq)
  seq = Counter({k: v for k, v in seq.items() if k in pat})
  pat_len = sum(pat.values())
  ct = 0
  elements = pat.keys()
  partitions = itertools.product(*(partition_n(seq[e] - pat[e], pat_len - pat[e] + 1) for e in elements))
  for part in partitions:
    ct += ct_for_one_partition(elements, part, pat)
  return Fraction(ct, grp_ct(seq.values()))

# Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18503391.
def partition_n(n, k):
  """n is the integer to partition, k is the length of partitions."""
  if k == 1:
    if n >= 0:
      yield (n,)
  elif k > 1:
    for i in range(n + 1):
      for result in partition_n(n - i, k - 1):
        yield (i,) + result

def grp_ct(ele_cts):
  return math.factorial(sum(ele_cts)) // reduce(mul, map(math.factorial, ele_cts))

def ct_for_one_partition(elements, part, pat):
  part = {e: iter(part[i]) for i, e in enumerate(elements)}
  ct = 1
  for ele in pat:
    other_ele = zip(*(part[e] for e in pat if e != ele))
    for _ in range(pat[ele]):
      ct *= grp_ct(next(other_ele))
  ct *= grp_ct(next(zip(*part.values())))
  return ct
```

I can't further reduce the nested summation to a formula. A fast program is good enough for me, but maybe someone interested can start from here.